# How to 1) list and extract specific 'li' tags in a 'ul' script in python and 2) export them in separate columns in excel

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape some data from a car site.

I have mananed to extract some details (e.g. price, title, subtitle) using beautiful soup, which sits under another tag, however, there are some li values (mileage, body, number of owners) under a ul tag which i havent been able to extract.

Below is my code i've been using:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

s = HTMLSession()
url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?postcode=CV23%208AJ&include-delivery-option=on&advertising-location=at_cars&page=1'
page = s.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="product-card__inner")

with open('autotraderdata.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    header = ['Price', 'Title', 'Subtitle', 'Year', 'Body', 'Miles', 'Engine', 'Power', 'Gearbox', 'Fuel', 'Owners', 'Ulez', 'One', 'Two', 'Three']
    thewriter.writerow(header)

    for list in lists:
        price = list.find('div', class_="product-card-pricing__price").text.replace('\n', '')
        title = list.find('h3', class_="product-card-details__title").text.replace('\n', '')
        subtitle = list.find('p', class_="product-card-details__subtitle").text.replace('\n', '')
        
        info = [price, title, subtitle]
        thewriter.writerow(info)

f.close()

print(lists)
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work for you? I don't see the code that attempts to extract information from `ul`s/`li`s

Comment: Do not post screenshots of the browser debugging tools.  You need to post the HTML you are trying to scrape as text if you are trying to troubleshoot this.  For example if those elements are inserted by javascript in the browser after the HTML fetch, they will not be available to you.

Comment: You also should revise your post to a single issue.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but don't name your variable `list`, that is a built-in python type already.

Comment: @Tarek [I didn't notice this was closed until I tried to post.] If you're interested, my suggested solution is [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/Driftr95/1357e99b0b9d373912a5fb7619ea7a03) (and the [output screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70u7B.png))

Answer (score 1):

Few things.

1. dont use `list` as a variable name. Thats a defined python method, so try to avoid using things like that (`int`, `str`, `for`, etc.)
2. use `.strip()` to remove that extra whitespace at the end of text instead of `.replace()`
3. Pandas is a great tool to use. Get familar with it. use it...it'll make life easier.

Lastly, this one is tough because not all that data is present, and there's no indicator to match up `"body"`, `"year"`, etc. So I made it slightly different, and if you want, you can split that `"Extra"` columns I created.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?postcode=CV23%208AJ&include-delivery-option=on&advertising-location=at_cars&page=1'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="product-card__inner")

data = []
for each in lists:
    price = each.find('div', class_="product-card-pricing__price").text.strip()
    title = each.find('h3', class_="product-card-details__title").text.strip()
    subtitle = each.find('p', class_="product-card-details__subtitle").text.strip()

    extra = each.find('ul', {'class':'listing-key-specs'})
    extra_lists = extra.find_all('li')

    row = {
        'Price':price,
        'Title':title,
        'Subtitle':subtitle,
        'Extra': '|'.join([x.text.strip() for x in extra_lists])
            }

    data.append(row)
        

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('autotraderdata.csv', index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
      Price                 Title                                                      Subtitle                                                                                      Extra
0      £395          Nissan Micra                                           1.0 16v Tempest 3dr                    2002 (02 reg)|Hatchback|103,565 miles|1.0L|60BHP|Manual|Petrol|5 owners
1      £900       Volkswagen Polo         1.6 TDI SE Hatchback 5dr Diesel Manual Euro 5 (75 ps)                     2010 (10 reg)|Hatchback|120,287 miles|1.6L|75PS|Manual|Diesel|5 owners
2    £1,200        Vauxhall Corsa  1.6i 16v SRi Hatchback 3dr Petrol Manual (189 g/km, 148 bhp)               2008 (08 reg)|Hatchback|79,828 miles|1.6L|148BHP|Manual|Petrol|5 owners|ULEZ
3      £695  Volkswagen Golf Plus                                             1.9 TDI PD SE 5dr                   2006 (06 reg)|Hatchback|149,000 miles|1.9L|103BHP|Manual|Diesel|3 owners
4      £995       Vauxhall Vectra                                          1.9 CDTi 16v SRi 5dr                               2006 (06 reg)|Estate|115,000 miles|1.9L|148BHP|Manual|Diesel
5    £1,995        Smart Roadster                                                       0.7 2dr          2004 (54 reg)|Convertible|136,000 miles|0.7L|80BHP|Automatic|Petrol|4 owners|ULEZ
6    £1,490           Ford Fiesta                                              1.25 Finesse 3dr                       2004 (53 reg)|Hatchback|120,000 miles|1.25L|74BHP|Manual|Petrol|ULEZ
7      £849            MINI Hatch                                         1.6 Cooper Euro 4 3dr                2007 (56 reg)|Hatchback|73,600 miles|1.6L|120PS|Manual|Petrol|6 owners|ULEZ
8      £500          BMW 3 Series          2.0 320i SE Saloon 4dr Petrol Manual Euro 4 (150 ps)                 2005 (55 reg)|Saloon|129,000 miles|2.0L|150PS|Manual|Petrol|10 owners|ULEZ
9    £1,350        Vauxhall Astra                                          1.6 16v Exclusiv 5dr                2010 (10 reg)|Hatchback|97,000 miles|1.6L|115PS|Manual|Petrol|3 owners|ULEZ
10  £26,900          KIA Sportage                                  1.6 T-GDi 2 Euro 6 (s/s) 5dr  SUV|1.6L|150PS|Manual|Petrol|First year road tax included|Full manufacturer warranty|ULEZ
```