# How to 1) list and extract specific 'li' tags in a 'ul' script in python with specific header and orga and 2) export them in separate columns in excel

Tags: pandas, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, header

Hi I am trying to web scrape some data from a comics site.

Thanks to the answer of chitown88 in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74222544/how-to-1-list-and-extract-specific-li-tags-in-a-ul-script-in-python-and-2)  I have managed to extract some details using beautiful soup, and some li values under a ul tag which I extracted but not organized like I want.

Below is my code i've been using:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bedetheque.com/serie-63733-BD-Champignac.html'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="album-main")

data = []
for each in lists:
    extra = each.find('ul', {'class':'infos'})
    extra_lists = extra.find_all('li')

    row = {
        'Extra': [x.text.replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '').replace('\xa0', '') for x in extra_lists]
            }

    data.append(row)
        
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(x) for x in df1.Extra])
df.columns = ['info_{}'.format(x+1) for x in df.columns]

df.to_csv('infos_albums.csv', index=False)
```

here is what I got :[here is what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXA9d.png)

and here is what I would like to have :[here is what I would like to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW65l.png)

I have a lot of comics to scrape and all the page are similar but some little specificity avoid me to use xpath method.

So if someone can help me or have a better idea it will be helpful (maybe put all the li in some variable??)

Thank a lot have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposition with *regex* (*based on your code*) :

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

pat= r"([^'\n:]+)\s*:\s*([^\n']*)"​
data = defaultdict(list)

for each in lists:
    extra_lists = each.find('ul', {'class':'infos'}).find_all('li')
    matches = re.findall(pat, '\n'.join([x.text for x in extra_lists]))

    for m in matches:
        data[m[0].strip()].append(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', m[1].strip()))
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index').T
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

  Identifiant Scénario        Dessin      Couleurs                       Dépot légal Achev. impr. Estimation Editeur        Format           ISBN Planches  Poids                                        Autres infos Autre image
0      354282     BéKa  Etien, David  Etien, David  01/2019 (Parution le 04/01/2019)      12/2018   non coté  Dupuis  Grand format  9782800174785       62  679 g  Créé le : 21/12/2018 (modifié le 07/03/2021 16:19)         Dos
1      413659     BéKa  Etien, David  Etien, David  02/2021 (Parution le 05/02/2021)      01/2021   non coté  Dupuis  Grand format  9791034749249       46  607 g  Créé le : 11/01/2021 (modifié le 07/03/2021 16:19)         Dos
2      467815     BéKa  Etien, David  Etien, David  04/2023 (Parution le 07/04/2023)      03/2023   non coté  Dupuis  Grand format  9791034768486       54   None  Créé le : 12/02/2023 (modifié le 07/04/2023 19:55)        None
```

Comment: **NB** : I'm not sure if we can handle the `Couleurs` *Olive, Céline* for the `Identifiant` 467815.

Comment: Thanks a lot with some little adjustment it's what I wanted!!

Answer (score 0):

You could get your goal in a "generic" way, working with [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) where as the `label` is the first index in its `list` if it contains a `:`, else you have to [`find_previous('label')`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous):

```
for ls in lists:
    d = {}
    for l in ls.select('.infos li'):
        if ':' not in l.label.text:
            d[l.find_previous('label').text[:-2]]=','.join([d[l.find_previous('label').text[:-2]], l.get_text(strip=True)])
        else:
            c = list(l.stripped_strings)
            d[c[0][:-2]]=','.join(c[1:])
    data.append(d)
```

###### Example

*Of course it could be improved to avoid all the indexing.*

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.bedetheque.com/serie-63733-BD-Champignac.html'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
lists = soup.find_all('div', class_="album-main")

data = []
         
for ls in lists:
    d = {}
    for l in ls.select('.infos li'):
        if ':' not in l.label.text:
            d[l.find_previous('label').text[:-2]]=','.join([d[l.find_previous('label').text[:-2]], l.get_text(strip=True)])
        else:
            c = list(l.stripped_strings)
            d[c[0][:-2]]=','.join(c[1:])
    data.append(d)

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

###### Output

|  | Identifiant | Scénario | Dessin | Couleurs | Dépot légal | Achev. impr. | Estimation | Editeur | Format | ISBN | Planches | Poids | Autres infos | Créé le | Autre image |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 354282 | BéKa | Etien, David | Etien, David,Guivarc'h, Clémentine | 01/2019,(Parution le 04/01/2019) | 12/2018 | non coté | Dupuis | Grand format | 9782800174785 | 62 | 679 g |  | 21/12/2018,(modifié le 07/03/2021 16:19) | Dos |
| 1 | 413659 | BéKa | Etien, David | Etien, David | 02/2021,(Parution le 05/02/2021) | 01/2021 | non coté | Dupuis | Grand format | 9791034749249 | 46 | 607 g |  | 11/01/2021,(modifié le 07/03/2021 16:19) | Dos |
| 2 | 467815 | BéKa | Etien, David | Etien, David,Olive, Céline | 04/2023,(Parution le 07/04/2023) | 03/2023 | non coté | Dupuis | Grand format | 9791034768486 | 54 | nan |  | 12/02/2023,(modifié le 07/04/2023 19:55) | nan |

Comment: Thanks a lot perfectly what I wanted!!! Nice!!